# Pressflow caching directives

Tags: caching

I have a setup with Varnish. Varnish decides when to clear the cache for a page according to the [PHP headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). I want to force Varnish to regenerate the cache for each node every time it gets updated by an user. I am looking for the best place to do this. Ideally it would be in a Drupal/pressflow hook (if there is any available) implemented in a custom module.

- What HTTP caching directives Pressflow sets?
- In what function, file and line number?

Answers that don't address those two bullet points will be appreciated, but not accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [varnish](http://drupal.org/project/varnish) module handles clearing the cache for you when a node is update via a socket connection to varnish. It can also be configure to clear the cache based on a lifetime period. If you still need to clear the cache based on your own custom requirements the module also provides a helper function such as _varnish_terminal_run that allows you to send commands to varnish from your php code.

Also in regard to the bullet point checkout the drupal_page_cache_header_external in pressflows [bootstrap](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~pressflow/pressflow/6/view/head:/includes/bootstrap.inc).inc file

There is also more documentation of varnish with pressflow over at [fourkitchens wiki](https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Configure+Varnish+for+Pressflow)

Comment: Oh yeah and the drupal_page_cache_header_external runs if you have set up your page caching to be external in the performance configuration page.